# Printing rows and columns in a 2D Array?

Tags: java

I'm having issues printing my 2d array... My ultimate goal is to have an output that looks like this:

```
0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   

19  36  45  44  47  
64  48  47  74  99  
55  7   48  12  21  
78  19  95  61  11
```

The first set of numbers prints out fine but I keep getting an error message after trying to print the second set along with it. What should I change in my code?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project
 Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
 package array2d;

/**
*
 * @author stevebrowning
 */
public class Array2d 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
         int [][] array2d = new int [4][5];

         array2d [0][0] = 0;
         array2d [0][1] = 0;
         array2d [0][2] = 0;
         array2d [0][3] = 0;
         array2d [0][4] = 0;

         array2d [1][0] = 0;
         array2d [1][1] = 0;
         array2d [1][2] = 0;
         array2d [1][3] = 0;
         array2d [1][4] = 0;

         array2d [2][0] = 0;
         array2d [2][1] = 0;
         array2d [2][2] = 0;
         array2d [2][3] = 0;
         array2d [2][4] = 0;

         array2d [3][0] = 0;
         array2d [3][1] = 0;
         array2d [3][2] = 0;
         array2d [3][3] = 0;
         array2d [3][4] = 0;

         int rows = 4;
         int columns = 5;
         int m, n;

         for ( m = 0; m < rows; m++) {
             for ( n = 0; n < columns; n++) {
                 System.out.print( array2d[m][n] + " ");
             }
             System.out.println( "")
             }
         }
          int [][] array2d = new int [][] {{19, 36, 45, 44, 47},
                                           {64, 48, 47, 74, 99},
                                           {55, 7, 48, 12, 21},
                                           {78, 19, 95, 61, 11}};
          for ( int i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++ )
            System.out.println( array2d[i] );
             }
```

Comment: Add what error you are getting and in which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first block works fine which means you need to follow the same to your next block. 
Replace the for loop as follows:

```
for (m = 0; m < array2d.length; m++) {
    for (n = 0; n < array2d[m].length; n++) {
        System.out.print( array2d[m][n] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println( "");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have  tried using the same method as the first section but I unfortunately keep getting errors... I replaced the for loop with this and I get an error for each line saying "class, interface, or enum expected". Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: You need to replace 
for ( int i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++ )
            System.out.println( array2d[i] );
             }
loop with the one I gave you.
Still getting errors ?

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, you have *two* loops; one for rows, one for columns.

In your second example, there is only *one* loop.

Why do you expect the same things to happen when you do things differently?

You see, the thing about programming is: details matter. You don't write down *some code*, you think carefully and write down the code that is required.

Finally: you should not hardcode the dimensions of your arrays - in this sense your second loop is better because it uses array.length instead of a manually assigned value.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you printing the second one like the first one?

```
 for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
             for ( j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                 System.out.print( array2d[i][j] + " ");
             }
             System.out.println();//no need for quotes in a line break

             }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize any element in the array, then all the elements in the array will be initialize to zero. so no need of loops for the above code.

```
   int array2d[][]=new int[4][4];

            array2d[0][0]=0;

            //to display the array2d
            for(int x[]:array2d){
                for(int y:x)
                         System.out.print(y+" ");
                System.out.println();
            }
```

replace the above code with this.

```
array2d = new int [][] {{19, 36, 45, 44, 47},
                        {64, 48, 47, 74, 99},
                        {55, 7, 48, 12, 21},
                        {78, 19, 95, 61, 11}};
for(int x[]:array2d){
                    for(int y:x)
                             System.out.print(y+" ");
                    System.out.println();
                }
```